# Magento2: error - rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods 500

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, http-error-500

After upgrade from Magento 2.3.6 to 2.3.7-p4 in checkout shipping method not showing.

I receive error:

logged customer

> rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id 500

as guest

> rest/default/V1/guest-carts/SirfT8sN2VOFvQHvEFz1e7VSm2WYj7DM/estimate-shipping-methods 500

I can't find a solution to this problem anywhere.

Comment: Have you check the magento log file while calling this?

Comment: just check in network response tab, there should be exact error.